# explanation of "passing const XXX as this disregards qualifiers"?

Tags: c++

I have the class

```
class Test {
public:
    void f() {}
    void g() const { f(); }
};
```

which fails to compile with

> error: passing 'const Test' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers (in call to void Test::f())

I realise that I should not call non-const `f` from const `g`. However, I don't understand the content of the message. Where does the `const Test` object come from, and what qualifiers are discarded (`f()` does not have any qualifiers)??

Comment: The `this` pointer is passed silently to the member functions (like `self` in python). You probably called the `const` member function `g` inside which you are calling a non-const member function `f`.

Comment: @Yashas: thanks. I suspected so, but why is it a `const Test` pointer. does the `const` member function convert it silently??

Comment: `const` qualifier on member functions applies to this object instance, not to function itself

Comment: @Yashas Again, don't answer in the comments section. Hover your mouse over the "add a comment" link (or read the heading of the section below) if you don't believe me.

Comment: Indeed. Answers in the answers section please @Yashas.

Comment: @MichaelVeksler: this is not at all similar. I'm asking for explanation of the error, not a solution

Comment: @MichaelVeksler: I literally wrote in my question what that answer says. I'm asking about the implicit `this` pointer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `this` pointer in a `const` member function is of type `const Test*`. That's how `const`-only member access is logically enforced. It's kind of an implementation detail, but a fairly reasonable one.

When you attempt to call `f()`, think of it as a hidden function argument being passed. The hidden function argument is the `this` pointer. `f()` is expecting a `Test*` but you're passing it a `const Test*`. A conversion between the two would "discard qualifiers", i.e. it would have to drop the `const`, which is not permitted.

The diagnostic is a little esoteric, I'll grant you, but it basically always means "you're trying to do a non-`const` thing in a `const` context".

Comment: Yes it's nice to have answers in the answers section since they can be peer-reviewed. This is a good answer in my opinion. Have an upvote.

Comment: @thanks. When I call a const function on a non-const object, where does the `const Test *` come from? is `this` constructed per function call??

Comment: @blue_note Yes, exactly, it's a magic pointer you get for free automatically. (Ultimately it really "comes from" the call site where you specified the object to call the function on, with `const` optionally added along the way if it's a `const` function you called)

Comment: @Bathsheba Increasingly uncommon to risk posting answers down here. I really don't get it. Couldn't be simpler! Some other SE sites have really cracked down on it, but SO resists for some reason. :( Personally I think having a tidy house is more welcoming than a big ol' mess

Answer (score 2):

It’s impossible<sup>1</sup> to call `f()` from `g()` as `g()` is `const` (which means the implicit `this` pointer is `const`), and `f()` is not `const`.

Hence compilation fails with, in your case, a helpful diagnostic.

---

<sup>1</sup> Well not *quite* impossible: A hack of which the behavior could be *undefined* if the object was *created* as `const` is

```
void g() const { const_cast<Test*>(this)->f(); }
```